# Android ClashRoyale-like border animation

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve this animation here:

[image]

I want to do something similar with a RelativeLayout having a `rounded corner background`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
   ... solid color etc code here ...
</shape>
```

I am trying to think of ways to animate it. What I have thought of is probably using 4 translation animator to animate in the 4 directions, finding the 4 corners of the RelativeLayout position. The shape of the animation got me thinking a little too. Initially I thought of achieving it with a `1dp height` rectangle shape, but it will not have the sort of sharp edges like the animation above. **Can i achieve that kind of shape without using an image?**

Any help pointing in the right directions as how to achieve this kind of animation will be greatly appreciated!